# calling file defined by variables and wildcard

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to loop through folders, defined by variables, and select a single file, defined by a wildcard (in matlab R2012a). An example file would be: /folder1/folder2/601/mprage/xyz.nii. In researching this, I've tried to incorporate the variables and wildcard via dir and fullfile, but am getting a horzcat (conversion to struct from char is not possible) error. Ultimately, the file would be processed by the function 'callspmsegmentation'. I am new to matlab programming... Here is my script:

```
clear all

studyDir = '/folder1/folder2';
anatDir = 'mprage';
subjects = {'601', '602', '603'};

for jSubj = 1:length(subjects)
niiname = dir(fullfile(studyDir, subjects{jSubj}, anatDir, '*.nii')); 
nii = [studyDir '/' subjects{jSubj} '/' anatDir '/' niiname];
callspmsegmentation(nii);
end
```

Alternatively, I tried the more direct: (which also didn't work)

```
clear all

studyDir = '/folder1/folder2';
anatDir = 'mprage';
subjects = {'601', '602', '603'};

for jSubj = 1:length(subjects) 
nii = [studyDir '/' subjects{jSubj} '/' anatDir '/*.nii'];
callspmsegmentation(nii);
end
```

Comment: Please provide the *full* error message and stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `dir` is a `struct` *not* a string, so you must access the `name` field to get the filename

```
niiname = dir(fullfile(studyDir, subjects{jSubj}, anatDir, '*.nii')); 
nii = [studyDir '/' subjects{jSubj} '/' anatDir '/' niiname.name];
```

I would also probably re-write it to use `fullfile` so that you don't hard-code all of those file separators. Something like this should work.

```
% Store the folder name
folder = fullfile(studyDir, subjects{jSubj}, anatDir);

% Get the file listing
file = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.nii'));

% Append the folder to the filename
nii = fullfile(folder, file.name);

% Process the file
callspmsegmentation(nii);
```